# Running thinkorswim

Tags: installation

I just started using ubuntu, and yesterday I managed to install thinkorswim software on my desktop. It was working yesterday, but now it doesn't work. I click it and nothing happens. Also the icon has changed to just a plain folder.

Other than going into settings I don't know what else to try.

How do I get this back working?

Comment: How did you install `thinkorswim`? What do you get when you type `thinkorswim` on a terminal. Press Ctrl+ Alt+t to open a terminal.

Comment: I successfully installed it sometime back on Ubuntu 12.04. Perhaps an update broke something? I'm looking into this possibility. Their tech support number is 800-672-2098. I'm currently looking at the Installing Updates screen.... More later

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Mine works fine (after a lengthy wait for updates).

Answer (score 3):

**Instructions for Lubuntu / Ubuntu 19.04**

Thanks to Michael in tech support at Thinkorswim.

> The following instructions should help you to install thinkorswim with
>   the proper version of Java:
>
> Installing Zulu OpenJDK:
>
> 1. Log in as root or use sudo
> 2. Import Azul's public key
>
>    ```
>    $ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 0xB1998361219BD9C9
>    ```
> 3. Add the Azul package to the APT repository
>
>    For Ubuntu
>
>    ```
>    $ sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://repos.azulsystems.com/ubuntu stable main'
>    ```
>
>    For Debian
>
>    ```
>    $ sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://repos.azulsystems.com/debian stable main'
>    ```
> 4. Update the information about available packages.
>
>    ```
>    $ sudo apt-get update
>    ```
> 5. Install Zulu by using the following command:
>
>    ```
>    $ sudo apt-get install zulu-8
>    ```
>
> Once Zulu is installed move on to installing ThinkorSwim:
>
> 1. Navigate to downloads and right click "thinkorswim_installer.sh", select "Properties"
> 2. Select the "Permissions" tab, and make sure "Allow executing file as program" is selected
> 3. Close the window
> 4. Double click "thinkorswim_installer.sh"
>
> -**IF ONLY A TEXT EDITOR OPENS, CLOSE IT AND CONTINUE BELOW**-
>
> 5. Click back onto the file explorer
> 6. Open from the top menu bar: Edit > Preferences OR Files > Preferences
> 7. Select the "Behavior" tab
> 8. Select "Ask each time" OR "Ask what to do" under "Executable Text Files"
> 9. Close the window and launch "thinkorswim.sh" and select "Run" from the prompt

Comment: I followed these instructions on 18.04.  At the end of the process, I told the installer to not create a shortcut.  How do I re-open the program now?  Do I just run the .sh file again?

Comment: @whitelightning There is a `thinkorswim` executable inside the installation directory (which is usually named `thinkorswim` as well).  Just call that as you would any other executable.  No need to re-run the installer.

Answer (score 3):

I had trouble getting this to run on Mint 19 due to having Java 11 installed by default and not wanting to set 8 as the default Java. Solved this here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/545041/running-thinkorswim-on-linux-mint-19

Copying answer here for ease of use:

> I tried a variety of things but the one thing that seemed to work best
>   is by making my own executable script and replacing the desktop
>   shortcut with it.
>
> So open a text editor/nano/vi/etc file and name it thinkorswim2 (or
>   whatever you want). In that put the following:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
>
> export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/:$PATH
> exec  /home/user/thinkorswim/thinkorswim "$@"
> ```
>
> Double check and make sure that the export path does match up on your
>   system by following it. It just goes to the directory of the java
>   executable.
>
> If you followed the install script defaults then change user to be
>   your home directory username. It installed to this directory by
>   default for my version.
>
> Now make that script executable. If you aren't used to the terminal
>   than right click -> properties -> permissions -> allow executing file
>   as program (or similar).
>
> If your like me you want the same icon too so (in mint cinnamon) go to
>   the basic tab in properties. Click the icon. Click browse and go to
>   "/home/user/thinkorswim" then press ctrl + H while browsing to reveal
>   hidden folders. go into "install4j" and pick "thinkorswim.png"
>
> Hopefully this saves someone time in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Piece of cake!!!

Step 0
Download and install thinkorswim app from the [website](https://www.tdameritrade.com/tools-and-platforms/thinkorswim/download-thinkorswim-desktop.page).

You should see a thinkorswim icon on your desktop once installation completes

Step 1
Run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`  #just note the java 8 path here and quit using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

Step2:
Create a file (`thinkswim.sh`) on desktop, with the following content:

```
#! /bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre  "this path should be set to what you get in step 1"

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME"/bin":$PATH

exec  ~/thinkorswim/thinkorswim "$@"
```

Step 3:
Run in a terminal

```
cd ~/Desktop
chmod +x  thinkswim.sh
./thinkswim.sh
```

You should see thinkorswim running now

Step 4(optional)
If you have a thinkorswim icon on your desktop:
**Right click it -> properties -> set command to `~/Desktop/thinkswim.sh`**

Now you can run the app by double clicking the icon

Comment: What in this answer is different than what is already posted?

Comment: the way java8 is installed. Agree that if you have java8 already installed, then you already have the answer. However, since recent changes in the oracle policy, java8 is harder to install. It does not work even if you do everything correctly (atleast did not work for me). This method worked for me, so just wanted to share.

Comment: This one help me, I needed to change the "alternative java" with sudo update-alternatives --config java   thx!

Answer (score 2):

Installing ThinkOrSwim trading application under Ubuntu

1: Install Oracle-java-jdk7
    Follow the tutorial here - http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

2: Download the Installer here - https://mediaserver.thinkorswim.com/installer/InstFiles/thinkorswim_installer.sh

3: Install: Make the script executable – right click on the file choose properties from the menu and tick the box as shown below. Note the location of the file. In this case it's in my Downloads folder.

[image: tos-permissions]

Now we are ready to install.

Open a Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and we will make a folder for installation
mkdir opt
cd ~
change to the folder where you downloaded the installer. In my case I'll type “cd Down” and hit the tab key then enter.
ls shows the contents of the folder. Enter the following:

`sh thinkorswim_installer.sh`

[image: tos1]

click Next. I always suggest reviewing privacy policies to insure you can accept them.

[image: tos2]

To continue choose I accept and click next.

Browse to the directory you have created.

My case is below:

[image: tos3]

Click OK:

[image: tos4]

Click Next:

[image: tos5]

Click Next:

[image: tos6]
Click Finish – Think or Swim will run

For now you can hit cancel at the logon screen. Type exit at any open terminal windows to close them. You'll find a shortcut on your desktop as shown below.

[image: tos7]

Right click – choose properties - click the permissions tab and tick the box to allow execution.

You can now run think or swim from the desktop icon. Expect a wait for installing updates. For assistance with the application contact TDAmeritrade.

Comment: @Matt I'm glad it worked for you too! Please make a habit of upvoting/accepting answers that work for you so that others with the same issue can find valid answers to their questions,

Comment: I did, but apparently I am not reputable enough for my vote to count

Comment: @Matt you'll gain that [privilege](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges) eventually. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a re-installation of `thinkofswim` think client. Thereafter double click on the icon to verify. You should see installing updates.

Answer (score 0):

Once that desktop icon was created, right clicking and selecting "Allow Launching" from the drop down list did the trick for me.