# Problem with Java and Ameritrade "thinkorswim"

Tags: 12.04, java, javafx

Ubuntu version 12.04

```
Java version "1.6.0_32"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.4) (6b32-1.13.4-4ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Here is the problem. I am trying to install Ameritrade's "thinkorswim" platform on my machine. They offer no support for the software on Linux, so I am turning to you guys for any help!

Basically, when the software is installing updates it runs into java errors, specifically:

```
Error catched  
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  
javafx/stage/Window
```

Here is a photo of the process:
[image]

This error is reached and the program just sits there not doing much of anything. I have done a lot of searching for what this error means, either on its own or in relation to "thinkorswim" with no luck. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue.

`Ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS`

```
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.2) (7u65-2.5.2-3~14.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

The problem as captured in the screenshot is pointing to missing java class. This is because thinkorswim client is expecting a SUN Java JRE rather than Open JDK.

Install Sun Java JRE should solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I used Oracle-java7 when I installed think-or-swim. It still works fine though I've since upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04. I used the instructions [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html) and obtained the installer [here.](https://mediaserver.thinkorswim.com/installer/InstFiles/thinkorswim_installer.sh)

After making the script executable, it installed fine and works fine. There's a full writeup on installing [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/394062/running-thinkorswim/634398#634398)