# Installing Thinkorswim on Ubuntu 20.04 lts

Tags: java

I've tried the solutions to install thinkorswim in other questions but nothing seems to work for me. I currently have Zulu OpenJDK 8.46. When I try to run the thinkorswim installer, nothing happens. I can post screenshots if it would help anyone give me some direction.

Update: I just wiped the hard drive and reinstalled Ubuntu. Going to try these solutions again

Comment: Did you try suggestions in https://askubuntu.com/questions/394062/running-thinkorswim ?

Comment: Yea I have. Not sure why these solutions aren't working for me. Being new to ubuntu doesn't help either. May have to wait until monday and call tech at tdameritrade

Comment: I downloaded and ran the installer from https://www.tdameritrade.com/tools-and-platforms/thinkorswim/download-thinkorswim-desktop.page and that worked with my default openjdk-11-jre, but when trying to run, there was a complaint about not having Oracle jdk-8 release 11 or later. Beter give more details about what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did a fresh reboot of ubuntu since I dont have any files. Followed the steps again and got it to work